# Issue in replacing single quote in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++

I have been seraching solution for this issue .Though this particular question has been discussed many times in this forum, i did not get any proper answer for my problem.

I will be getting data from 3rd party which can contain single quote.This data need to be inserted into data base and when it contains single quote it fails and throws following error:

```
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '
```

---Following is c++ code to pass trandata as input along with other parameters and invoke fn_stripsingleQuote10 function from SQL server:

```
strSQLText = "declare @returnType as varchar(max)\n EXEC @returnType = CABINET..fn_stripsingleQuote10 ";
sqlTxtParams.Format("'%s', '%s', '%s', tranData, sing_quote, double_sing_quote);

strSQLText += sqlTxtParams;
```

----My sql function(fn_stripsingleQuote10) to replace single quote

```
USE [cabinet]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE function [dbo].[fn_stripsingleQuote10](
 @strip varchar(Max),@patern varchar(5),@replace varchar(5)
 )
returns varchar(Max) as begin

 declare @CleanString varchar(Max)     
    SET @CleanString=(REPLACE(@strip,@patern, @replace))

 return @CleanString
end
```

sample output:
ex:
declare @returnType as varchar(max) EXEC @returnType = CABINET..fn_stripsingleQuote10 'fsds'd','''',''''''

I feel the way i am invoking the function is not proper.Please provide a solution .

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you're looking for [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx), which does exactly what you're asking:

> `'quote_character'` Is a one-character string to use as the delimiter.
>   **Can be a single quotation mark ( ' )**, a left or right bracket ( [ ] ),
>   or a double quotation mark ( " ).

However, it is very very likely that your code is exposed to SQL Injection right now and you should actually use a parameter. It is almost never *required* to concatenate input into the resulted executed SQL.

Comment: Quotename wont work for data having more than 128 characters and my input contain large data. Could you please tell me what do you mean by "you should actually use a parameter". I am sorry I am new to SQL. I am already passing parameter for my SQL function arguments.

Comment: Use parameters: Instead of building up a text containing the `"'%s', '%s', '%s', tranData, sing_quote, double_sing_quote`, use `@param` and set the parameter value. What is you execution API? OleDB (ADO), ODBC, SqlClient (ADO.Net managed C++)? Each one has different way of setting up the parameters.

Comment: ODBC: [Binding Parameters in ODBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712522(v=vs.85).aspx), OleDB [Using Parameters in OleDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722661(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. We use ODBC API and it worked fine when i started using parameter . But When my input data is more (say length of char : 18617) SQLBindParameter fails giving the error as: ODBCSql server Invalid precision error. I am trying to insert data to column of varchar(max) type. I use SQL server 2008. Could you provide a solution for this ?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131462(v=sql.100).aspx, specially the discussion about `SQL_SS_LENGTH_UNLIMITED`. Make sure you connect using the SQL Native Client driver.